# Как верстать такую секцию что бы было отзывчивым?

Tags: вёрстка

есть такая несложная секция, характеристики
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно заметить слева у нас идут ключ справа значения
Правые пункты подстраиваются справа независимо какая ширина у левой, при этом самая длинная левая иметь небольшой отступ от правой
Вопрос такой, как сверстать что бы если в будущем левая часть будет длинее автоматом все подстраивались под нее

Интересует если это возможно **лишь на CSS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  /*долго думал, пока не вспомнил про это значение*/
  width: max-content;
}

li {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
}

div:first-child {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem:</div>
    <div>Lorem</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur:</div>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor:</div>
    <div>lorem</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cпасибо за прекрасный пример